# Replace id with class in this code?

Tags: jquery

```
 $(".menu dt a").click(function() {

 var clickedId = "." + this.id.replace(/^link/,"ul");
```

In the second line above, I want to replace id with class,

I tried

```
 var clickedId = "." + this.attr("class").replace(/^link/,"ul");
```

But the code above doesn't worked and showed me the following error in console

> this.attr is not a function

Any hints how can I use a class instead of id ?

Comment: `$(this)`, not `this` to have a jQuery object. `this` is a DOM element

Comment: wrap `this` as an jquery object `$(this)` instead

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean

```
$(this).attr
```

instead of

```
this.attr
```

`this` in an event callback will return the HTML DOM element, to have a jQuery object, use `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

also you can use `this.className`:

```
var clickedId = "." + this.className.replace(/^link/,"ul");
//-------------------------^^^^^^^^^--this way
```